# C# - generic methods vs. non-generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I'm a bit confused about why/when I'd ever want to use a generic method since a non-generic method can access the generic members of its containing class and be passed generic arguments anyway.

So, using a canned example that likely misses the point (yet highlights why I'm asking this question), why would I do this:

```
public class SomeGeneric<T>
{
    public T Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
    {
        T tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
}
```

over

```
public class SomeGeneric<T>
{
    public T Swap(ref T a, ref T b)
    {
        T tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
}
```

this?

Or, really, why would I want to use a generic method *at all*?

Comment: For the most part, *either* a method *or* a class is generic.  It's rarely both.  In your first example it's actually a problem because T is ambiguous between the class and method definition; they should have different names, but semantically you don't want to different types.  Needing two generic arguments, with one at the class and one at the method level can happen, it's just...rare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd typically use a generic method in a type that isn't generic.

For example, look at the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).  It defines the generic extension methods for most of the LINQ fucntionaltiy, but itself isn't generic.

You also might want a generic method within a generic type, but only if the generic method used a *different* generic type specifier.

This lets you write something like the following:

```
 class Foo<T> where T : IConvertible, IComparable<T>
 {
      int CompareTo<U>(U other) where U : IConvertible
      {
           // Convert to this
           T otherConverted = Convert.ChangeType(other, typeof(T));
           return this.CompareTo(otherConverted);
      }
 }
```

(Granted, this is a bit contrived, but does compile and work correctly for `Foo<int>` comparing to a `double`, etc)

Answer (score 4):

What if the containing class is not generic? What if it has different generic type parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The first example does not make much sense, because class parameter is not used. Consider another example though:

```
public class SomeGeneric<T>
{
    public K ConvertTo<T>(T a)
    {
         return CodeThatConvertsTtoK(a);
    }
}
```

and its usage:
`new SomeGeneric<int>().ConvertToInt("ten");`

Comment: That should be `public K ConvertTo<K>(T a)` (the compiler will complain with it as-is)

Answer (score 1):

A common scenario for method level type parameters are extension methods because they must be declared in a non-generic static class. But they are required for every generic member in a non-generic type.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Foo<A, B>(this A a, B b) { [...] }

    public static T Bar<T>(this String input) { [...] }

    public static U FooBar<V, W>(this V v, W w) { [...] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If both the class and the method are generic, the type parameters ("generic parameters") must have different names, of course. There can't be two different things named `T` like in your first example.

If your method is non-static (as it seems), if you choose to make the containing class generic, the type will have to be specified already when you instantiate your class. Like `var obj = new SomeGeneric<DateTime>();`. So it should be something that logically "belongs" to the object modelled by the class.

If your method is static, and you choose to make the class generic, you will still have to specify the type parameter together with the class somehow. If the method is called from outside the class, it would go like `SomeGeneric<DateTime>.Swap(ref a, ref b);`.

The advantage with making the *method* generic, is that in many cases you can use **type inference** which allows you to omit the angle bracketed type parameter. You can only do this with generic *methods*. Example: `nonGeneric.Swap(ref a, ref b);` where the `Swap<T>` method is generic. The compiler will look at the compile-time types of `a` and `b` and figure out which `T` fits in, without you specifying it.

Conclusion: If the `T` does not logically belong to the class (as in `List<T>`), put it with the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example where generic methods really shine. Consider an expression such as `1+2` expressed as a binary tree. You want to implement the Visitor pattern on the entire tree, with the goal being some sort of map/reduce operations. Some examples would be:

- Reducing an expression to a `string` to print it
- Reducing an expression to a `double` to calculate its value
- Mapping an expression to another expression with some members altered/added/removed

All of these operations can be put behind a Visitor pattern method:

```
public abstract class Expression
{
  public abstract T Reduce<T>(ITransformer<T> transformer);
}
```

This is similar to the classic Visitor implementation, but the terminology is changed: we have `Reduce()` instead of `Accept()` and an `ITransformer<T>` instead of an `IVisitor`. Notice that the method is generic.

This approach allows us to create any number of `ITransformer<T>` classes that transform the hierarchy to any type T, supporting map-reduce operations.