# Generic interface taking generic interface as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to design an interface to take one `IEnumerable`, enhance it with some additional data from another `IEnumerable` and return the first one back. Something like:

```
interface IEnhanceable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> EnhanceWith(IEnumerable<aGenericType> foo);
}
```

One approach I'm considering is to create an abstract empty model class, from which all other model classes would inherit and pass this one as parameter. However I'm not sure if this would be the right way to do it.

Comment: What is the problem with that approach? `IEnumerable<aTypeInModels> EnhanceWith<anotherTypeInModels>(IEnumerable<anotherTypeInModels> foo);`

Comment: I edited the example, so perhaps it is more clear. I would like to have foo as IEnumerable of another generic type. Hopefully this would be more clear.

Comment: Still unclear... I suspect you are asking how to write generic method - `IEnumerable<T> EnhanceWith<aGenericType>(IEnumerable<aGenericType> foo)` - please confirm (and explain what you have problem with doing so).

Comment: I put the thing you wrote into my code. To my huge suprise this is accepted by VS, but I'm not sure what's going on here. Could you advise or give me some link what is the construction here with the way this method is called     EnhanceWith<aGenericType>?

Comment: Maybe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959392/c-sharp-generic-methods-vs-non-generic-methods explains it for you? If not try following search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+generic+type+vs.+generic+method.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much Alexei. It seems you helped me to discover the generic methods, which I was not aware of. I will need to study this a bit more. I will be happy to accept if you make your thoughts an answer.